# Who earned most reputation from a single post?

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer

[Kyle Hale on Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28603/kyle-hale) has earned almost 10,000 reputation even though he's only ever made one single post on the site. Is this a network record?

**Among users with just one post on a site, who has the most reputation from that one post?**

- It doesn't matter if they have many posts on other network sites. I'm interested in the most reputation from a single post on a single site.
- If possible, it would be nice to exclude reputation earned from suggested edits on that site (which I think can be up to 1k reputation without any posts).

Comment: _Is this a network record?_ Apparently, not even close . Not even in the top 50 (#74 currently; according to Glorfindel's query below).

Comment: @41686d6564 Yep, some pretty amazing stats on Stack Overflow, as usual. (Kyle Hale's SFF answer *is* the [most bountied post on the entire network](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396019), which is why I thought it plausible that he might be the highest-rep one-shot wonder too.) He'll be #60 when the currently active bounty is awarded.

Comment: @41686d6564 It is 9th when [we ignore Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425286/users-with-more-than-1000-reputation-with-a-single-post). Still not a record but closer to the top.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Will be 5th soon if we ignore SO, after two on SU and two on AU (ranging from 19k to 13k).

Comment: There's a few people with over 20K on SO and zero posts, is that better than reputation earned for one post?

Comment: @Rob The highest I've found was just under 5K. I used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1425456/1751839/users-with-no-posts-but-with-reputation-1000).

Comment: @41686d6564 I just searched for over half an hour, I can't dispute your comment; though I remember seeing some oddly high rep without posts, certainly higher than 5K. Found this slightly better query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/919052/users-with-max-reputation-by-n-number-of-posts?maxRows=100&maxPosts=0  
and this query for all sites except SO:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1425374/1751756/top-users-without-a-single-post-top-user-per-site

Answer (score 14, accepted):

User [@MattShane on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13161/mattshane) currently has 85,769 reputation while his only contribution is the question [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/4751173)

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425277/users-with-more-than-1000-reputation-with-a-single-post) is the relevant SEDE query; the top 15 are all from Stack Overflow.

[image]

If you're interested in the single post top users of a specific site, you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1425275/top-users-with-only-a-single-post) instead.

[image]

Finally, as suggested by @rene, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425335/top-users-with-only-a-single-post-top-user-per-site) is a version with the top user for each site.

Comment: You can maybe add the top 1 for each site in the network to prevent stack overflow being overly dominant in these kind of "rankings"

Comment: @rene [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1425374/top-users-without-a-single-post-top-user-per-site) is also interesting :) Perhaps you can help out with Stack Overflow.

Comment: well, the indexes on the PostsWithDeleted table are not going to help there. It looks I get a slightly better performance on SO if I first spool all records from Posts to a temp table and then set an index. But that is not going to fly for all sites I'm afraid.

Comment: @rene [this version (filtering on 101+ rep upfront) works](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425370/top-users-without-a-single-post) but the cross-site version is still too slow.

Comment: Hmm, times out for me if I want to execution plan as well.

Comment: Does this one work for you: https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1425553/top-users-without-a-single-post-top-user-per-site ?

Comment: Well done @rene!